# Sql issue of selecting max value from a grouped column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi guys actually I have a problem .

```
  select * from Insurance_Plan;
  select * from Enroll;
  select * from Patient;
```

These three are the tables in my database. Now I have to the get the insurance plan with the most patient enrollees, and for that plan, its name, required copayment amount, and the number of patient enrollees.

I have done that part till here:

```
 Select I.Insurance_Name,Max(I.Insurance_Copayment_Amount) As 
   Copayment_Amount,count(P.Patient_ID) As Number_Of_Patients
   From Insurance_Plan as I inner Join 
   Enroll AS E on I.Insurance_Plan_ID=E.Insurance_Plan_ID
   inner join Patient as P on P.Patient_ID=E.Patient_ID
   group by Insurance_Name
```

As a result I am getting the output:
         [image]

Now I want to show only the insurance plan with max number of patients enrolled which is the second row in the output shown. I am trying to use Max function but getting errors. It has to be done in a single efficient query.

Comment: I removed the `mysql` tag from this question -- that screen shot has to be from `ssms`. Feel free to update if I'm incorrect, just don't tag both databases...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Select top (1) I.Insurance_Name,Max(I.Insurance_Copayment_Amount) As 
   Copayment_Amount,count(P.Patient_ID) As Number_Of_Patients
   From Insurance_Plan as I inner Join 
   Enroll AS E on I.Insurance_Plan_ID=E.Insurance_Plan_ID
   inner join Patient as P on P.Patient_ID=E.Patient_ID
   group by Insurance_Name
   order by count(P.Patient_ID) desc
```

Comment: hey thanks ... But by adding 3 in order by clause we change it from dynamic to being manually done. So any other way

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

```
having Max(Number_Of_Patients) = Number_Of_Patients
```

at the end of the query.

[Here you will find a good example for having-max.](http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/having.php)